# Code returning address

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C at home (already know java from university).
I'm just trying to run some basic functions but It seems I'm getting the adrees instead of the value..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDepartureDate (int day, int month, int year); 

int getReturningDate (int retDay, int retMonth, int retYear);

int getNoOfCountries (int countries);

int getNoOfTravellers (int noOfTravellers);

int main() {

    int day; int month; int year; int retDay; int retYear; int retMonth; int countries; int travellers;
    printf("Please enter the departure date");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year);
    printf("Please enter the returning date:");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&retDay,&retMonth,&retYear);
    printf("Please enter the number of countries:");
    scanf("%d",&countries);
    printf("Please enter the number of travellers:");
    scanf("%d",&travellers);
    printf("Your information is: \n");
    printf("Your departure date is: %d \n",&getDepartureDate);
    printf("Your returning date is: %d \n",&getReturningDate);
    printf("Your number of countries are: %d \n",&getNoOfCountries);
    printf("Your number of travellers is: %d \n",&getNoOfTravellers);
    return 0;
}


int getDepartureDate (int day, int month, int year)
{

return ("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year);
}

int getReturningDate (int retDay, int retMonth, int retYear)
  {

return ("%d %d %d",&retDay,&retMonth,&retYear);
  }

  int getNoOfCountries (int noOfCountries)
  {

return ("%d",&noOfCountries);
  }

  int getNoOfTravellers (int noOfTravellers)
  {

return ("%d",&noOfTravellers);
  }
```

Note: I also tried to use the functions like that:

printf("Your departure date is: %d \n",&getDepartureDate(day,month,year));

So when I run the programm it returns:
Your departure date is: 45687, something like that for all the methods..
Maybe it's not possible to use getters this way in C?

Comment: You need to read up on pointers and how to pass by reference.

Comment: &var means address of var

Comment: What material are you using to learn C? I'm sure it covers return values and should tell you what you are doing makes no sense. Please review a basic C book or tutorial.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler scream at you when you try to return an address in a function with int return type? You should enable all warnings in your compiler. `return ("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year);`

Answer (score 2):

`&getDepartureDate` and `getDepartureDate` for that matter are *function pointers*.

The arguments to `printf` are typically not pointers, but values. It's also important to note that the argument types must match the format specifiers *exactly* else the behaviour of your entire program will be *undefined*.

Did you mean

`printf("Your departure date is: %d \n", getDepartureDate(day, month, year));`

etc.? Note that I've supplied the *parameters* to the function `getDepartureDate`.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe it's not possible to use getters this way in C?

No, it is not possible to do it like that.

There are some things that you seem to have misunderstood so I'll try to explain.

#### 1) Returning a string

From your code it seems that you want your functions to return a formatted text string with the relevant information.

In order to do that you must return a `char*` (char pointer) as strings in C are a zero-terminated char arrays that you can refer to using a char pointer.

So use

```
char* getDepartureDate(....)
{

    return SomeCharPointer;
}
```

#### 2) Building a formatted a string

There are several ways to build a formatted string. A simple method is `sprintf`. It works nearly the same way as `printf` except that it requires a `char*` as first argument. The `char*` shall point to the location of a char array sufficiently large to hold the formatted string (see end-note).

So you need to a) create a char array and b) use `sprintf`

Again - it can be done in several ways - but to keep things simple, you can make the char-array in `main`and the pass to the functions.

```
int main() {
  char str[128];

  ....
  return 0;
}

char* getDepartureDate (char* str, int day, int month, int year)
{
  sprintf(str, "%d %d %d", day, month, year);
  return str;
}
```

#### 3) Calling a function

In your code you try to call the function like `&getDepartureDate`

That is not the correct way to do it. Instead you write

```
functionName(argument1, argument2, ......)
```

So to call a function like:

```
char* getDepartureDate (char* str, int day, int month, int year)
```

you could do:

```
char s[128];
int d=29;
int m=12;
int y = 2016
getDepartureDate (s, d, m, y);
```

Notice that the variable names used when calling doesn't have to match the variable names in the function prototype. It is only the type that needs to match.

#### 4) printf format specifier

When using `printf` (and `sprintf` and other friends) it is important to use the correct format specifier.

You used `%d` but that is for printing an integer.

To print a string you must use `%s`

#### Putting it all together

So rewriting your code using the above guidelines will give you:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* getDepartureDate (char* str, int day, int month, int year);

char* getReturningDate (char* str, int retDay, int retMonth, int retYear);

char* getNoOfCountries (char* str, int countries);

char* getNoOfTravellers (char* str, int noOfTravellers);

int main() {
  char str[128];

  int day; int month; int year; int retDay; int retYear; int retMonth; int countries; int travellers;
  printf("Please enter the departure date");
  scanf("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year);
  printf("Please enter the returning date:");
  scanf("%d %d %d",&retDay,&retMonth,&retYear);
  printf("Please enter the number of countries:");
  scanf("%d",&countries);
  printf("Please enter the number of travellers:");
  scanf("%d",&travellers);

  printf("Your information is: \n");
  printf("Your departure date is: %s \n", getDepartureDate(str, day, month, year));
  printf("Your returning date is: %s \n", getReturningDate(str, retDay, retMonth, retYear));
  printf("Your number of countries are: %s \n", getNoOfCountries(str, countries));
  printf("Your number of travellers is: %s \n", getNoOfTravellers(str, travellers));
  return 0;
}


char* getDepartureDate (char* str, int day, int month, int year)
{
  sprintf(str, "%d %d %d", day, month, year);
  return str;
}

char* getReturningDate (char* str, int day, int month, int year)
{
  sprintf(str, "%d %d %d", day, month, year);
  return str;
}

char* getNoOfCountries (char* str, int noOfCountries)
{
  sprintf(str, "%d", noOfCountries);
  return str;
}

char* getNoOfTravellers (char* str, int noOfTravellers)
{
  sprintf(str, "%d", noOfTravellers);
  return str;
}
```

**end-notes**

In general `sprint` must be used with care as a buffer overflow will occur if the char array is too small for the formatted text. Instead you can take a look at `snprintf` as it lets you specify a maximum size.

Also notice that using `scanf` without checking the return value is in general bad. So instead of `scanf("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year)` do:

```
if (scanf("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year) != 3)
{
    // ERROR - Input was not 3 integers
    ... add error handling ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions do not really do anything useful. You can simply remove them and use this code below.

```
int main() {

    int day; int month; int year; int retDay; int retYear; int retMonth; int countries; int travellers;
    printf("Please enter the departure date");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&day,&month,&year);
    printf("Please enter the returning date:");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&retDay,&retMonth,&retYear);
    printf("Please enter the number of countries:");
    scanf("%d",&countries);
    printf("Please enter the number of travellers:");
    scanf("%d",&travellers);
    printf("Your information is: \n");
    printf("Your departure date is: %d \n",Day);
    printf("Your returning date is: %d \n",retDay);
    printf("Your number of countries are: %d \n",countries);
    printf("Your number of travellers is: %d \n",travellers);
    return 0;
}
```